# AWS Websocket API return error "Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200" when testing to connect from wscat

Tags: aws-api-gateway, integration

I am trying to build realtime chat and notification using AWS Websocket API. i have setup the $connect route to integrate to http endpoint. when testing the websocket URL using wscat, request successfully received on my endpoint, but wscat got "Unexpected server response: 500".  inspecting associated log on CloudWatch, i found an error said "Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200". anyone can please help me to figure out what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: have you solved it please?

Answer (score 1):

This stems from a missing Method Response on the method.

- Select the API Gateway Method
- Select Method Response
- Ensure that a mapping exists for a 200 response (either 200 or 2**)

Comment: Does Method Response refer to RouteResponse?

Comment: @sayandcode It refers to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-response.html

Comment: I see. I can't see this applicable to the websockets in the question tho. What do you think? Is there some parallel?

Comment: Perhaps not.  I experienced the same error when working with the HTTP API (due to bad config).  Perhaps the ApiGatewayV2 has been configured as the wrong ProtocolType or perhaps there's an issue with the initial HTTP handshake for establishing the connection.  Hard to say without more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that despite having configured the response routes correctly with a `$default` response (as a catchall), the deployment did not contain these integration responses.

This was due to the deployment resource being created before the actual routes. I solved it by adding making the *stage* `DependsOn` the route, and the deployment `DependsOn` the stage (this I did by using an implicit dependsOn via a `StageResource.ref` for the stageName attribute on the deployment).

You can check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75457275/18620006) for more details.