# Why does cloudformation give "Invalid method response 200" error, but manual deployment work? (AWS API Gateway Websocket)

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am getting this error when I deploy a simple websocket mock route.

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: Output mapping refers to an invalid method response: 200
```

First of all, I'm a little confused about what *method response* means, as in Websocket API, the terminology used is *Route Response* and *Integration Response*. I'm guessing this is referring to the *Route Response*.

The resources I have are:

- Websocket API
- Stage
- Deployment
- $connect route
- $connect integration with mock (default maps to `{"statusCode": 200}`)
- $connect integration response (just passes the integration through)
- $connect route response

The funny part is: to fix this, **all I have to do** is go to the console and click `deploy API`. I don't have to change any configuration. But that is not a good solution for me, as I want to run this on a CI/CD pipeline.

I'm guessing the problem is with the *Route Response*, as that is not configurable from the console. So something must be going on behind the scenes during console deployment, which I am missing during cloudformation deployment. Any ideas how to solve this?

Here's my Cloudformation Template.

```
Resources:
  testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      Name: testWsApi
      ProtocolType: WEBSOCKET
      RouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.action

  testWsApiApiDeployment423ACBB9:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Deployment
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
    DependsOn:
      - MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockRoute04DB7577
  testWsApiApiStageF40CAAE0:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
      StageName: production
      DeploymentId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiApiDeployment423ACBB9
          - DeploymentId

  MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockRoute04DB7577:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
      RouteKey: $connect
      Target:
        Fn::Join:
          - ""
          - - integrations/
            - Ref: MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockIntegration36E7A460

  MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockIntegration36E7A460:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
      IntegrationType: MOCK
      PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
      RequestTemplates:
        $default: '{"statusCode":200}'
      TemplateSelectionExpression: \$default

  MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockRouteResponseAEE0B8ED:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::RouteResponse
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
      RouteId:
        Ref: MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockRoute04DB7577
      RouteResponseKey: $default

  MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockIntegrationResponse85928773:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::IntegrationResponse
    Properties:
      ApiId:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - testWsApiBackendWsApi40DF2EE8
          - ApiId
      IntegrationId:
        Ref: MockWithAuthAwsStackwsMockIntegration36E7A460
      IntegrationResponseKey: $default
      TemplateSelectionExpression: \$default
```

P.S I am actually using AWS CDK. The above template is the result of `cdk synth`. Let me know if you want to see the CDK code.

Comment: So deploy in console manually and then use AWS CLI to inspect values of integration and routes that the console does in the background.

Comment: @Marcin Yeah I tried a form of that using the [former2 website](https://www.former2.com). The values seem to be the same with or without console deployment. Do you think this could be because of the deployment resource being internally created before the actual routes?

Comment: Sometimes you have to explicitly add `DependsOn` to some resources. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why manual deployment using console works, while using cloudformation causes errors occasionally, is due to the order in which these resources are created. In the console, this is the order followed:

1. Routes, Integrations and Responses are created
2. They are associated with a stage
3. They are deployed to the specified stage

When using cloudformation, the order of creation of resources gets mixed up, resulting in them not being wired up properly. It seems that you have wired up the *deployment* to depend on the *route* being created first. You also need to make sure that the *stage* is created before the *deployment*. For this you could add an explicit `DependsOn` attribute, or an implicit reference to the *stage* within the *deployment*; perhaps in the *stageName* attribute as `!Ref StageResource`.
Or you could save the trouble and just add an `autoDeploy: true` to your stage, which will take care of the linking and order on its own.